# dotnet run x.csproj "... libhostfxr.dylib could not be found."

Tags: .net-6.0

Running a .NET Core project on a Mac with .NET 6.0 installed causes a strange error.

```
 lukepuplett@Lukes-Air > ~/Documents/Git/Repo/src/Corp.App.Mvc > > master ± > dotnet run Corp.App.Mvc.csproj 
A fatal error occurred. The required library libhostfxr.dylib could not be found.
If this is a self-contained application, that library should exist in [/Users/lukepuplett/Documents/Git/Repo/src/Corp.App.Mvc/bin/Debug/net5.0/].
If this is a framework-dependent application, install the runtime in the global location [/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64] or use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable to specify the runtime location or register the runtime location in [/etc/dotnet/install_location].

The .NET runtime can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=osx.11.1-x64&apphost_version=5.0.12
```

Note that the project builds fine.

macOS Monterey, Apple Silicon M1 and .NET 6.0 is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can occur when the project is targeting an older .NET Core version. The error is confusing because the project may build okay, and you'd expect a more accurate message.

A better message can be seen when executing the compiled binary directly, see below.

```
 lukepuplett@Lukes-Air > ~/Documents/Git/Repo/src/Corp.App.Mvc/bin/Debug/net5.0 > > master ± > dotnet Corp.App.Mvc.dll
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' (arm64) was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      6.0.0 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=5.0.0&arch=arm64&rid=osx.11.1-arm64
```

The problem can happen when you've pulled down code from a Git repo that is targeting .NET Core 5, for example.